# How to copy variable values within an SPSS file?

Tags: data-analysis, spss

I have three seperate SPSS files with information about roughly 7500 hemicolectomy patients. One file contains the information about the hemicolectomies, the second one about other surgeries the patients have had during their lifetime and the last one contains information about their sick leaves during their lifetime.

I have merged (`idnumber` is the common variable) the files to a single SPSS document but i ran into a problem with filtering out the surgeries and sick leaves that have nothing to do with the hemicolectomy. I'm quite new to SPSS so the simplest way i could think of doing this is by somehow copying the hemicolectomy info to every case and then just using the date/time calculator to choose which sick leaves and surgeries to discard. Switching to wide format is unpractical due to the large number of unrelated surgeries and sick leaves: I'd have thousands of variables.

So basically I'd like to do the following:

`IF idnumber = idnumber THEN variable1=variable1 AND variable2=variable2` etc

How would I go about doing this?

All help will be appreciated!

Comment: I posted an answer, but then realized: is your data patient-level data, or surgery-level data (i.e. - one row of data represents one patient or one surgery ?)

Comment: At first it was surgery-/sick leave level. In it’s current form one row contains info from one surgery or sick leave and emty variables from the other two datasets.

Answer (score 1):

the IF command can only be used with one transformation:
IF [condition] [transformation].

Assuming both of your files are sorted by `idnumber`:

```
UPDATE file=[master_file_reference]
/file=[secondary_file_reference]
/BY idnumber.
EXECUTE.
```

The file reference can be made either by their dataset name, or by their full path.

More on the UPDATE command:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLVMB_24.0.0/spss/base/syn_update_examples.html

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment yet, so Im sorry if I misunderstand the problem. I wouldve asked for clarification in the comments to the question... here goes...

So you have three sources of data which have dates (?) of hemicolectomies, one for each case; dates (?) of other surgeries, multiple for each case; and sickleaves even more for each case. Is that right?

I'd try solving the problem before matching all three file by matching the file that contains one observation per patient (presumably hemicolectomies) to the one with the second most observations (presumably other surgeries) per patient with the /table keyword:

```
MATCH FILES /FILE= 'surgeries.sav' /table = 'hemicolectomies.sav'
/by idnumber.
EXECUTE.
```

this will "fill up" the blank cells for each patient with the hemicolectomy data.

now use the datetime to check which surgeries "belong" to the hemicolectomies, thus reduce your data and match it to the sickleave data using the /table keyword again.

Seems like the easiest solution to me.